# Counting reads within the intron

Tags: rna-seq

I have paired-end RNA-seq samples and a list of intron coordinates in bed format. I want to count the intronic reads such that:

```
1. The reads should overlap the intron by atleast 25 bp 
2. If both the reads of the pair are within the intron, count it as 1.
```

What tool can I use to compute it.

Thanks

Comment: How are your reads stored? Are they `BAM` or are they `BED`. If they are `BED` how is the pairing encoded?

Comment: Hi,
My reads are in bam file, I can convert them into bed file. I am trying to follow what you did with your written scripts. Although I am having issues following how you calculated effective length under null model. I am trying to first make a non overlapping set of introns just like DEXseq manual says for exons

Answer (score 3):

You could use [BEDOPS](https://github.com/bedops/bedops) `bedmap` to map reads to introns, using 1) the `--count` operator to do counting of reads overlapping by your criteria; and, 2) the `--indicator` operator to do a true/false operation, where reads are contained entirely within the intron.

For instance, to count reads that overlap introns by at least 25 bases, use `--count` to count and `--bp-over 25` to specify the minimum overlap threshold:

```
$ bedmap --echo --count --bp-ovr 25 --delim '\t' introns.bed reads.bed > answer.counts.bed
```

To filter for introns where reads are contained entirely within the intron, use `--indicator` to get introns that meet the criteria of full containment of reads, via `--fraction-map 1`:

```
$ bedmap --indicator --echo --fraction-map 1 --delim '\t' introns.bed reads.bed | awk '($1==1)' | cut -f2- > answer.indicator.bed
```

Once you have `answer.counts.bed` and `answer.indicator.bed`, you can compare those two results with `bedmap --indicator --exact` to see where there are commonalities (true/1) and differences (false/0), and increment the final count where there are identical introns, e.g.:

```
$ bedmap --indicator --echo --exact --delim '\t' answer.counts.bed answer.indicator.bed | awk '{ $NF += $1; print $0; }' | cut -f2- > answer.final.bed
```

If your reads are in a different format, i.e. BAM, you can use `bam2bed` in a process substitution, replacing `reads.bed` with `<(bam2bed < reads.bam)`, e.g.:

```
$ bedmap --echo --count --bp-ovr 25 --delim '\t' introns.bed <(bam2bed < reads.bam) > answer.counts.bed
```

Etc.

You can also just convert separately, so that you only need to do it once:

```
$ bam2bed < reads.bam > reads.bed
$ bedmap --echo --count --bp-ovr 25 --delim '\t' introns.bed reads.bed > answer.counts.bed
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex,
Can you explain what is --indicator and --fraction-map doing in generating answer.indicator.bed. I don't get this part?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation, as it goes into much more detail: http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/statistics/bedmap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can almost do what you want using `featureCounts` from the `subread` package. The only problem is that featureCounts requires GTF rather than bed.

If you had a GTF of your introns, you could do:

```
featureCounts -a introns.gtf my_bam.bam -f -p --minReadOverlap=25 -o counts.tsv
```

---

The problem with this then, is getting the `GTF` when you currently have a `BED`.
One way to get the `GTF` would be to use `CGAT`.

```
cgat gtf2gtf -I ensembl.gtf.gz --method=merge-exons -S genes.gtf.gz
cgat gtf2gtf -I genes.gtf.gz --method=exons2introns -S introns.gtf
```

or you could put this together into one pipeline:

```
cgat gtf2gtf -I ensembl.gtf.gz --method=merge-exons  | cgat gtf2gtf --method=exons2introns -S introns.gtf
```

This will first merge all the exons of a gene together to make a single, collapsed transcript. It will that invert this to find that parts that are in the introns of this collapsed transcript. What you end up with is parts of the gene that are never exonic in any of the transcripts.

alternatively, you could convert your bed regions into GTF:

```
cgat bed2gff -I introns.bed -S introns.gtf --as-gtf
```